# SQLDataException: invalid datetime format from HSQLDB

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to make a test of JDBC. I'm creating tables from schema.sql file and I'm inserting data into tables from data.sql file. When I'm trying to make a test, I get an error:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid datetime format
```

and

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'engine' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/mydocuments-jdbc-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'documentDAO' while setting bean property 'documentDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentDAO' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/mydocuments-jdbc-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid datetime format
```

I don't understand why, because my date format is correct: for example

```
'2014-02-24 11:52'
```

so, in documentation is the same example about date format.
Here's my mydocuments-jdbc-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="engine" class="spring.service.SearchEngineService">
        <property name="documentDAO" ref="documentDAO"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="documentDAO" class="spring.data.DocumentRepository" init-method="initialize">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="schema" value="classpath:META-INF/data/schema.sql"/>
        <property name="data" value="classpath:META-INF/data/data.sql"/>
        <property name="queryAll">
            <value>
                select d.documentId, d.name, d.location, d.description as doc_desc, d.typeId, d.created, d.modified,
                t.name as type_name, t.description as type_desc, t.extension from documents d
                join types t
                on d.typeId = t.typeId
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and here's my data.sql file

```
INSERT INTO types (typeId, name, description, extension) VALUES ('41e2d211-6396-4f23-9690-77bc2820d84b', 'PDF', 'Portable Document Format', '.pdf');
INSERT INTO documents (documentId, name, location, description, typeId, created, modified) VALUES ('431cddbf-f3c0-4076-8c1c-564e7dce16c9', 'Pro Spring Security Book', 'http://www.apress.com/9781430248187', 'Excellent Book', '4980d2e4-a424-4ff4-a0b2-476039682f43', '2014-02-14', '2014-02-20');
```

Comment: What column type is `documents.created` and  `documents.modified` ?

Comment: created datetime NOT NULL,
  modified datetime NOT NULL,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to modify your `data.sql` file to a valid datetime value, not just date-values:

```
INSERT INTO documents (
  documentId, name, location, description, typeId, created, modified) 
  VALUES ('431cddbf-f3c0-4076-8c1c-564e7dce16c9', 'Pro Spring Security Book', 
  'http://www.apress.com/9781430248187', 
  'Excellent Book', '4980d2e4-a424-4ff4-a0b2-476039682f43', 
  '2014-02-14 00:00:00', '2014-02-20 00:00:00'
);
```

Comment: Wow, It's worked! But, I can not see any difference about my and your code, can you explain it please? Because in another example I added hours minutes and secondes, and it doesn't work too.

Comment: In your code the last two values for `created` and `modified` are just `2014-02-14` and `2014-02-20` - without the time. Your way the database thinks it will get a data-only field.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Comment: OIC, you meant date-only field, @Benvorth. Couldn't figure out what you were saying, LOL.